# how to use .map() in nodelist in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why am i getting this error? How can i access and print the nodes when i'm selecting the `<li>` tags with `querySelectorAll`?

`script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: list.map is not a function`

**HTML**

```
<ul class="wrapper1" id="testDiv">
        <li class="cake">Carrots</li>
        <li class="cake">Cake</li>
        <li class="cake">Wheat</li>
        <li class="cake">Balloons</li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
 let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        let items = list.map(elem => {
      console.log(elem);
    })
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. Use `array#from` to convert NodeList to array then iterate through `array#map`.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let items = Array.from(list).map(elem => {
  console.log(elem);
})
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper1" id="testDiv">
    <li class="cake">Carrots</li>
    <li class="cake">Cake</li>
    <li class="cake">Wheat</li>
    <li class="cake">Balloons</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you didn't call your variable "list." It's not a list, and even if it was, that would be a confusing choice of name. This kind of thing is a common hurdle for me in programming tutorials.

Comment: seems weird we have to allocate a new array instead of being able to iterate over something with List in the type name

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Itang and Foo's suggestion, you can also use:

```
[].concat(document.querySelectorAll("li")).map((el) => { console.log(el); })
```

In fairness I think Foo's suggestion using spread syntax Is probably the most elegant, I'm just not sure how widely the spread operator is supported for NodeLists.  (pasted below for reference)

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map((el) => { console.log(el); })
```

Comment: Spread operator is widely supported, Safari 8 and up. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=spread%20operator)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using ES6, you can use `[...selectors]` syntax, like this:

```js
let getMappingList = function (list) {
  console.log(typeof list);

  for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  
  console.log("___________________");
  
  list.map(item => console.log(item));
};

getMappingList([...document.querySelectorAll("li")]);
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper1" id="testDiv">
    <li class="cake">Carrots</li>
    <li class="cake">Cake</li>
    <li class="cake">Wheat</li>
    <li class="cake">Balloons</li>
</ul>
```

After getting the list, we can also use `map` function, or looping the list using `for...of...` syntax.

---

`Array(...selectors)` is the same way to use:

```js
let getMappingList = function (list) {
  console.log(typeof list);

  for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  
  console.log("___________________");
  
  list.map(item => console.log(item));
};

getMappingList(Array(...document.querySelectorAll("li")));
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper1" id="testDiv">
    <li class="cake">Carrots</li>
    <li class="cake">Cake</li>
    <li class="cake">Wheat</li>
    <li class="cake">Balloons</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but listed as #1 on Google search result. So here is an alternative to those in need.

```
let items = [].map.call(list, item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: this has the upside of working on legacy browsers

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the question of how to use a nodelist (result of document.querySelectorAll) with .map on my project and solved it by using a SPREAD operator to create an array from the nodelist.

Learning as I go so don't hesitate to correct me. It's weird that modern browsers can directly execute a foreach function to a nodelist but not map.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let items = [...list].map(elem => {
  console.log(elem);
})
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper1" id="testDiv">
    <li class="cake">Carrots</li>
    <li class="cake">Cake</li>
    <li class="cake">Wheat</li>
    <li class="cake">Balloons</li>
</ul>
```

edit : understood how snippets work / SPREAD not REST